# AWS TransferManager returning more bytes transferred than file size, causing hang

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3transfermanager

I'm using AWS's Java SDK to upload some files (>130 MBs) into an S3 bucket.

The issue I'm having is that during the upload process (using `TransferManager`), the `getBytesTransferred()` returns a number greater than that of the file size itself.

This is causing my Progress Dialog to hang at 100%.

Am I missing some sort of configuration?

I should point out that this doesn't happen all the time.

```
public class PutFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, UploadZipCode> {

    @Override
    protected UploadZipCode doInBackground(final Void... params) {

        // Initialize S3 Client
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(mS3AccessKey, mS3SecretKey);
        AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

        mTransferManager = new TransferManager(credentials);

        mUploadStart = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Upload myUpload = mTransferManager.upload(mS3UploadBucket, mFile.getName(), mFile);

        myUpload.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
            long totalBytesTransferred = 0;

            @Override
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {

                totalBytesTransferred += progressEvent.getBytesTransferred();
                Log.d(TAG, "Bytes transferred = " + totalBytesTransferred);

                onProgressUpdate(totalBytesTransferred);\

                if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE) {
                    cancel(true);
                } else if (progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.FAILED_EVENT_CODE
                        || progressEvent.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.CANCELED_EVENT_CODE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Uploaded erred out with AWS Event Code: " + progressEvent.getEventCode());
                    cancel(true);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Setting completion code to: " + progressEvent.getEventCode());
            }
        });

        try {
            myUpload.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            cancel(true);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return UploadZipCode.CONNECTION_ERROR;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            cancel(true);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return UploadZipCode.AWS_ERROR;
        }
        return UploadZipCode.UPLOAD_SUCCESS;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading your session zip file...");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(mProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
        mProgressDialog.setMax((int) (mFile.length()));
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        for (long value : values) {
            mProgressDialog.setProgress((int) value);
        }
    }
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(UploadZipCode resultCode) {
        super.onPostExecute(resultCode);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mListener.onUploadFinished(resultCode);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(UploadZipCode resultCode) {
        super.onCancelled(resultCode);
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        mListener.onUploadFinished(resultCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: `onProgressUpdate(totalBytesTransferred);\ ` Normally one would not call that function. You would call `publishProgress()`. Please try to change. I wonder: do you have to use an asynctask? Isn't the manager async by it self?